# transitive or intransitive verb

Tags: grammar

i have problem to determine if the word **bake** is transitive or intransitive  verb from the Phrase "Samantha can bake at any time of the day." i am reading from a book called English grammar understanding the basic it say

> Action verbs that act upon something are called transitive verbs.
>   Action verbs that do not act upon something are called intransitive
>   verbs.

If a verb (in any of its forms) can be put in one of the following slots, it is transitive: (a) What did you_____? (b) Who did you______ ? If a verb cannot be put in one of these slots, it is intransitive.

> If a verb (in one of its forms) can be put in one of the following
>   slots, it is transitive: (a)  He _____ something. (b) He____ someone.
>
> If a verb (in one of its forms) can be put in the following slot, it
>   is intransitive: He____

by following the grammar i can say "he bake something" or "what did you bake" it look transitive for me

Comment: Some verbs can be both transitive and intransitive. *Bake* is one of those. "I am baking a cake." "The cake is baking in the oven right now."

Answer (score 2):

"Bake" is an [agentive ambitransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambitransitive_verb), a verb that can be either transitive or intransitive. English has many of these. "Eat" is another example:

> Joe eats.
>   Joe eats apples.

In the sentence about Samantha, "bake" is intransitive. There is no object. The sentence doesn't tell us what Samantha is baking, just that she bakes.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of transitiveness is a subset of the technical definition of [verb-valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)) in linguistics.

When we delve on the subject of verb-valency, we should no longer use the term "transitive verb". We should walk on a higher plane, with more grandiose pedestals and say "transitive usage of a subject of a verb". Alternatively, "transitive dependencies of a verb." A similar topic of concern is found in transitive dependencies and valencies of a database/information entity.

What qualifies as subjects worthy of transitive action of a verb might still be in trivial dispute.

- He came eating.
  Is *eating* qualified to be the transitive-subject of *come*?
- He came *yesterday*.
  Why would adverbial use of *yesterday* not qualify as valency of a verb??
- She gave *me*.
  And yet *me* qualifies as valency?
- He came *groaning*.
  Why wouldn't *groaning* increment the valency of *came*?
- She gave *a cake*.

AFAIAC, all subjects above qualify as transitive-subjects of its verb, not intervened or mediated by any preposition. Some people may disagree with me, limiting themselves to the initial thesis on linguistic valency-of-verbs. Perhaps, I am contorting the intents of that thesis. Perhaps, current people indulgent in that thesis attempt to concoct an algorithm to restrict the term *valency*, without considering the mathematical implications of such restrictions.

1. Valency 0:

   - *Giving* is such a *blessing*.
2. Valency 1: One action-subject to the verb in a phrase.

   - *Giving **presents*** is a blessing.
   - **He** bakes.
     The perpetrator is the sole subject of the verb.
3. Valency 2:  Two action-subjects per verb. Valencies 1 & 2:

   - *Giving me(v1) presents(v2)* is his delight.
   - He(v1) bakes cakes(v2).
   - He(v1) baked yesterday(v2).
   - He(v1) baked laughing(v2).
4. Valency 3:

   - *He(v1) giving me(v3) presents(v3)* is his delight.
   - He(v1) bakes me(v2) cakes(v3).
   - He(v1) baked cakes(v2) groaning(v3).
5. Valency 4:

   - *He(v1) giving me(v3) a kiss(v3) yesterday(v4)* was amusing.
6. Valency 5:

   - I am amused when *he(v1) gave me(v3) a kiss(v3) groaning(v4) yesterday(v5)*.

Test of valency: A subject increases the valency of a verb, when that subject can be used with the verb independent of any other valency candidates.

- *he(v1) gave me(v3) a kiss(v3) groaning(v4) yesterday(v5)*.
- he gave
- gave me
- Q: When did he give you a kiss?
  A: He gave yesterday.
- Q: How did he give you a kiss?
  A: He gave groaning.
- He gave a kiss

Answer (score -1):

It is transitive. There is an implied object.

The intransitive verb is also "to bake" but this is not it.

**Examples**

The cakes are baking in the oven.  (Intransitive - no object)

Samantha is baking in the kitchen.  (Transitive - implied object)

Comment: but the book say it is Intransitive

Comment: Samantha is baking in the sun. She should put her bikini back on, and bask in the bikini.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - Thanks. Yes, I was aware of that meaning and of course it would be intransitive. The context tells us which.

Comment: @Skube - Then the book is wrong.